# What kind of DC/AC motors can be used to run a small electrical car?

Tags: motors

I'm trying to design a small one wheeler electrical car which will be driven by a motor. However, I have no background in electrical or electronics and I just have a really basic idea of motors. As the title says, I need some help figuring out which motor to use for the vehicle.

The motor need not be a very powerful one, just enough to say, power an electrical scooter but the vehicle might be a bit lighter than a scooter. It should be powerful enough to help the vehicle climb a bit of a gradient but not too much.

As the vehicle is moderately heavy already, it would help if the motor were light weight although that is not my main criterion.

Thanks everyone!

Comment: Unfortunately this question is difficult to answer on several accounts. This is kind of a chicken and egg scenario. The motor size and how long you want to run will dictate the size of the batteries. If you want to go the other way then the batteries and desired run time will give you the size of the motor. Then there is a controller problem and if you want regenerative breaking. The absolute simplest is an induction motor and a variable frequency drive. This won't give you regenerative braking. Everything else gets more complicated.

Comment: Huge one piece fan. Love the user name.

Comment: not really the right site. Try engineering.stackexchange.com

Comment: I think all the ground work has already been done... https://bestelectrichoverboard.com/reviews/self-balancing-unicycle-reviews/the-best-electric-unicycle-reviews-2016/

Comment: @PeteCon - You should pull the info from that website and bring it here.

Comment: @vini_i :) i'm surprised that name wasn't taken; thanks for the help!
PeteCon i'll have a check at the site!
agentp thanks!

Comment: Cool question. Can you give us some dimensions for car? Size weight. How many passengers? Intended speed/range. If speed is not a big concern then gearing could open up a wide range of options of donor engines. Also direct drive vs thru diff/gearbox.

Comment: @Peter the one wheeler is just about 50cmX50cmX100cm in dimensions, speed isn't of importance. I'm not sure how much it will weigh but it will be just around a small scooter at max. It will be a direct drive

Comment: I might be a bit slow but its still not clear to me what you mean by scooter. Do you mean mobility scooter? Search  Google images for scooter and youll see what i mean.

Comment: How heavy is heavy? Is it a big RC toy? Or will it carry a human passenger?  Are we talking 20kgs or 120kgs loaded?

Comment: oh my bad, i meant the human passenger carrying type scooter, the one with a seat and all so it should weight around 250 lbs

Comment: Check out https://onewheel.com/

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about engineering a new design, not maintenance or repair.